# Using multiple variables in $min & $max in $group

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to write a query that incorporates multiple variables that go into $min and $max in order to find the smallest and the biggest variables of each.

The query I need is:
For each of the airlines, find the delay category that contributes the minimum delay and find the airport where this airline has the most delays in this category.

I tried writing the following but it doesn't work:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "carrier",
    "min": {
      $min: {
        "arr_del15",
        "carrier_ct",
        "weather_ct",
        "nas_ct",
        "security_ct",
        "late_airport_ct"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Could you please advice how am I supposed to use multiple variables?

Thank you very much.

[This explains the data I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Ob7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an example say we have the following data inserted in to our mongo database:

```
db.data.insertMany([
    {carrier: "AAA", a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4},
    {carrier: "AAA", a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5},
    {carrier: "BBB", a: 3, b: 4, c: 5, d: 6},
    {carrier: "BBB", a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4},
    {carrier: "CCC", a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5},
    {carrier: "CCC", a: 3, b: 4, c: 5, d: 6}
]);
```

We can then write a simple aggreation query with a project to start with that will get the current min and max values for that document, then chain it with a groupby to get the min and max values for all the carriers:

```
db.data.aggregate([
   { $project: {
      "carrier": 1,
      min: { $min: [
               "$a",
               "$b",
               "$c",
               "$d"
            ]
      },
      max: { $max: [
               "$a",
               "$b",
               "$c",
               "$d"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   { $group: {
      _id : "$carrier",
      min: { $min: "$min" },
      max: { $max: "$max" }
      }
   }
]);
```

This will then output our expected result of:

```
{ "_id" : "CCC", "min" : 2, "max" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "BBB", "min" : 1, "max" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "AAA", "min" : 1, "max" : 5 }
```

Comment: db.delayData.aggregate(     {"$group" : {"_id" : "$carrier" , delay :{"$avg":  "$carrier_ct"}}})
This got me the average for the carrier_ct category but I need the average for all the categories and I need to know in which airport the delay occurs.